# JSON delete specific keys from nested objects without knowing key names

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file and want to delete some subkeys i don't need. Here is some part of the JSON file :

```
{
  "peers":{
    "swp1":{
      "hostname":"Spine-01",
      "remoteAs":65001,
      "version":4,
      "msgRcvd":452,
      "msgSent":459,
      "tableVersion":0,
      "outq":0,
      "inq":0,
      "peerUptime":"00:19:15",
      "peerUptimeMsec":1155000,
      "peerUptimeEstablishedEpoch":1635674862,
      "prefixReceivedCount":30,
      "pfxRcd":30,
      "pfxSnt":43,
      "state":"Established",
      "idType":"interface"
    },
    "swp2":{
      "hostname":"Spine-02",
      "remoteAs":65001,
      "version":4,
      "msgRcvd":452,
      "msgSent":459,
      "tableVersion":0,
      "outq":0,
      "inq":0,
      "peerUptime":"00:19:14",
      "peerUptimeMsec":1154000,
      "peerUptimeEstablishedEpoch":1635674863,
      "prefixReceivedCount":30,
      "pfxRcd":30,
      "pfxSnt":43,
      "state":"Established",
      "idType":"interface"
    }
  }
}
```

for example, i want to delete the "version" subkey, and i already tried this command

```
del(.peers.swp1.version, .peers.swp2.version)
```

and it worked well. But the thing is, the "swp1" and "swp2" are the interfaces and are something that can change their name, increase or decrease. So I need a command that works to delete the "version" subkeys no matter what the interface name is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `map_values` and `del`.

```
.peers |= map_values(del(.version))
```

demo in [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/wWp6bG_2D7)

Comment: @Chloe: Click on tick-mark next to answer to mark the post resolved and upvote the `^` the answer if you found it useful

Comment: ok!! and if u don't mind, i have another question... I have other keys (other than "peers") such as "name", "id", and "memory". I want to delete the keys "memory", and at this moment I'm still using command del(.memory) so have to run two commands (along with the one you suggest). is there a way so i can run it in just one command?

Comment: @Chloe Stackoverflow does not encourage follow-up questions on the same post after accepting the answer. Please ask a new question with your _proper_ input and an expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this syntax :

```
del(.peers[].version)|del(.memory)
```